# Lubuntu hangs after locking

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, freeze, lock-screen

A friend asked me to take care of his Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. He is not a computer expert at all so his bug report might not be accurate. Unfortunately I could not reproduce the error while I am at his Lubuntu box.

He reports that when he does not touch the computer for, let's say ten minutes, then it becomes locked and he was not able to give his password, so it hangs and he has to reboot the computer. Unfortunately I did not see this so this description might not be precise.

There is no power management software running on the computer, I checked.

Which menu entry should I check then to disable this locking? I can do command line so that kind of answer is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe light locker is installed on his system. Try uninstalling light locker if so:

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
```

And install xscreen saver instead of it:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra
```

See here for more info: [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240075&p=13102289#post13102289)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with `light-locker` causing my computer to hang. As suggested in another answer `xscreensaver` works, but it doesn't look very nice. Using `gnome-screensaver` works for me, and keeps a consistent theme with the rest of the system:

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```